# How to add port to each host in list of lists?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have a list of lists of hosts:

```
[['host-0', 'host-1'], ['host-2', 'host-3'], ['host-4', 'host-5', 'host-6']]
```

How can I add a port number, e.g., 8000, to each host using ansible/ jinja2 to get:

```
[['host-0:8000', 'host-1:8000'], ['host-2:8000', 'host-3:8000'], ['host-4:8000', 'host-5:8000', 'host-6:8000']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` + `regex_replace`.

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ foo | map('map', 'regex_replace', '$', ':8000') }}"
      vars:
        foo: [['host-0', 'host-1'], ['host-2', 'host-3'], ['host-4', 'host-5', 'host-6']]
```

```
    "msg": [
        [
            "host-0:8000",
            "host-1:8000"
        ],
        [
            "host-2:8000",
            "host-3:8000"
        ],
        [
            "host-4:8000",
            "host-5:8000",
            "host-6:8000"
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

this task shall do it:

```
  - name: convert items in list
    set_fact:
      my_new_list: "{{ my_new_list | default([])+ [ my_var ] }}"
    vars:
      my_var: "{{ item | map('regex_replace', '$', ':8000') | list }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ my_list }}"
```

full playbook to run as demo:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_list: 
    - ['host-0', 'host-1']
    - ['host-2', 'host-3']
    - ['host-4', 'host-5', 'host-6']

  tasks:
  - name: print original variable
    debug:
      var: my_list

  - name: convert items in list
    set_fact:
      my_new_list: "{{ my_new_list | default([])+ [ my_var ] }}"
    vars:
      my_var: "{{ item | map('regex_replace', '$', ':8000') | list }}"
    with_items:
    - "{{ my_list }}"

  - name: print new variable
    debug:
      var: my_new_list
```

result:

```
TASK [print new variable] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_new_list": [
        [
            "host-0:8000",
            "host-1:8000"
        ],
        [
            "host-2:8000",
            "host-3:8000"
        ],
        [
            "host-4:8000",
            "host-5:8000",
            "host-6:8000"
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP
```